# What does the notation $\partial_{x,y} f$ mean?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, notation, partial-derivative, jacobian

For example, if I have a function $f \colon \mathbb{R}^4 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $f(x,y,z,w)=(xyz+w^2,x-w-zy^2)$, what does it mean to find the following matrix:

$\partial_{p} f(p,q)$ where $p=(x,y)$ and $q=(z,w)$

My lecturer used this notation in his notes, but never really explained what it means or gave an example. Is it just supposed to be the Jacobian of $f$ but with the columns for $z$ and $w$ removed?

Comment: That is shorthand for the partial derivative with respect to $p$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Yes but $p=(x,y)$. How would I find the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to 2 variables? In my notes it is explicitly stated that it is a matrix.

Comment: Look at the solution by below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed this is just the notation for a 'part' of the Jacobian.

In general, if you have a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{d}\to\mathbb{R}^{k}$, then you define $\partial_{p}f$ with $p=(x_{1},\dots,x_{l})$ for some $l\in\{1,\dots,d\}$ as

$$\mathcal{J}_{f}(x)=:(\partial_{p}f(x),\partial_{q}f(x))$$

where $\mathcal{J}_{f}(x)$ denotes the Jacobian and $q=(x_{l+1},\dots,x_{d})$.

So in this general example $\partial_{p}f$ would be

$$\partial_{p}f(x):=\begin{pmatrix}\partial_{x_{1}}f_{1}(x) &\dots&\partial_{x_{l}}f_{1}(x)\\ \vdots&\ddots&\vdots \\\partial_{x_{1}}f_{k}(x) &\dots&\partial_{x_{l}}f_{k}(x)\end{pmatrix}$$